# Maven/Spring autowiring not working

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am stuck at an error: "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency"
I am new to Spring. I ran "mvn spring-boot:run" and have the following code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    private MyServiceTest myServiceTest;
......
}

public class RemotePossessionServiceTest {
...
}
```

But still I am getting "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency" error on myServiceTest. My package name is "hello". This is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="hello" />
<bean id = "myServiceTest" class="hello.MyServiceTest"></bean>
```

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RRRRR</display-name>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: is MyServiceTest declared with Component annotation ?

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-servlet-2-5) to make Spring Boot work with a traditional `web.xml`?